# iMac stuck since update

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, big-sur

I'm on an IMac mid 2017
I tried to update my Mac running under Mojave to Big Sur. I got an error that the disk check couldn't be done.
Since if I boot the mac in normal mode I can't start it, it gets stuck on the apple logo.
So I wanted to reset the mac but when I open the disk utility via Mac Restore it loads endlessly and doesn't display the disks.

I count on this precious community to help me.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you boot into safe mode and have you tried resetting NVRAM/SMC. Since you mention that a disk error occurs and disk utility does not show any disks, can you boot from an USB installer or external hard drive? can you restore your iMac from a backup? Do you hear any weird sounds like chirping or similar, which may indicate a broken hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

There’s only two things to do.

1. Connect this Mac to another in target disk mode and use a second Mac to erase / test the storage.
2. Boot to internet recovery and follow the precise exact steps. If you select the wrong part of a disk or the wrong image, the erase will fail.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

• boot from an Install USB, made on another Mac - OR -

• Restart in Recovery. Open terminal. Unmount (eject) all containers of the PHYSICAL disk (probably disk0), then close terminal, open DiskUtility hoping that you’re able to test the problematic container by mounting them - one at a time.
My guess is it’s the container named [Your Systemdisk] / “Update.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”.

I do admit chances are low but it’s free to try.